# Control for variables in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm pretty new to the charting software tableau. I'm trying to draw some distribution graphs of price per square meeter in tableau:[image]

The price is impacted by two variables i know, time of sale

[image]
and total size of the house.
[image]

Can I somehow control for theese variables in tableau or should I use another tool for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box, Tableau does not have a way to weight variables into Box-plots.

However, as you mention that you are new to Tableau, it is worth noting that '[Calculated fields](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields.htm)' are a way that you may customize, aggregate, or qualify your underlying data. These fields can be as simple or as complex as the provided functions will allow.

Another consideration is that statistical packages like [R](https://www.tableau.com/solutions/r) and scripting languages like [Python](https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2016/11/leverage-power-python-tableau-tabpy-62077) can be linked to Tableau. These tools can be leveraged to perform more complex series of calculations on underlying data. This allows for you to port your Data Science familiarity over to a tool like Tableau.

Comment: Thanks, I looked a bit at "calculated fields". What I would like to do is something like  AVG([sqmPrice])/avg['month', totalPrice], where sqmPrice is the value for that sale and totalPrice is the value for all sales that month. Would that be possible? What is it called?

Comment: Take a look at LOD Calculations in that case. They are able to aggregate across things like ‘Months’ and then perform calculations on those aggregations.

Comment: I tried them out, didn't get it working though... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55581604/why-is-my-calculated-area-price-always-the-same-as-the-price