# Why is my calculated area price always the same as the price?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to draw a table with two columns, the avg price on that street and the calculated avg price in that area. (Every area has multiple streets)

On rows I have streets. On the columns I have price and sqmPrice. myArea  is a calculated field:

```
{ INCLUDE [myArea] : AVG([sqmPrice]) }
```

For some reason these are always the same, I would expect the area-column to always show the same value if the streets were in the same area.
[image]
With myArea added, for clarity:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you will need to used '[FIXED](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_fixed.htm)' and amend your calculated field to:

```
{ FIXED [myArea] : AVG([sqmPrice]) }
```

Comment: Wow, would you look at that!

Comment: LODs are...fun. (My usual go-to is to mash the keyboard and eventually they work.) If you're able to dedicate the time to understanding them, though, they become very useful.

Comment: Yea, they are really powerful, though, I instantly hit a wall when I tried to do this. `{ FIXED [myArea] : AVG([sqmPrice]) } / [sqmPrice]` it always equals 1.

Comment: Strange. Works for me. It could be that the number formatting is set to show integers. Right click on your calculated field > default properties > number format > custom/percentage.